# How to pass variable name from controller to twig file in Symfony?

Tags: php, twig, symfony4

I need to display image at my twig file. I am passing filename information as below:

```
    $emailContent = [
        'filename' => "$filename.png"
    ];

    $this->sendMail(
        ,,,
        ...
        'Emails/content.html.twig',
        $emailContent
    );
```

In my twig file, when I put the filename directly it works.

```
<img src="{{ email.image("@images/1000.png") }}" alt="It Works!!">
```

But, I am not sure how to pass filename from controller to twig html file.

I already tried following lines:

```
<img src="{{ email.image("@images/{{ filename }}") }}" alt="test ONLY">
<img src="{{ asset("images/logo/") ~ filename }} " alt="???" />
```

It didn't worked.

Can anybody please help.

Comment: `<img src="{{ email.image("@images/" ~ filename) }}" alt="test ONLY">`?

Comment: @biesior yes its my custom method which later sends email using TemplatedEmail of Symfony

Comment: Thanks u_mulder , it worked. I understand my mistake. Many Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use concatenation for argument of `email.image`:

```
<img src="{{ email.image("@images/" ~ filename) }}" alt="test ONLY">
```